# python pandas - use dataframe value in ewm parameters

Tags: python, pandas, mean, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name" : ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"],
    "score_1" : [306, 236, 93, 420, 396, 22, 218, 338, 246, 1, 0, 341, 364, 339, 327, 105, 122, 350, 420, 410, 414, 470, 309, 329],
    "score_2" : [204, 380, 388, 83, 334, 471, 218, 90, 194, 256, 213, 198, 132, 366, 101, 229, 493, 220, 248, 276, 232, 437, 56, 153],
    "span" : [3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    "min_periods" : [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
})
   name  score_1  score_2  span  min_periods
0     a      306      204     3            2
1     b      236      380     1            1
2     c       93      388     2            2
3     a      420       83     3            2
4     b      396      334     1            1
5     c       22      471     2            2
6     a      218      218     3            2
7     b      338       90     1            1
8     c      246      194     2            2
9     a        1      256     3            2
10    b        0      213     1            1
11    c      341      198     2            2
12    a      364      132     3            2
13    b      339      366     1            1
14    c      327      101     2            2
15    a      105      229     3            2
16    b      122      493     1            1
17    c      350      220     2            2
18    a      420      248     3            2
19    b      410      276     1            1
20    c      414      232     2            2
21    a      470      437     3            2
22    b      309       56     1            1
23    c      329      153     2            2
```

each value of "name" has a "span" and "min_periods" value, i would like to use them as value in ewm parameters.
Instead of having a fixed value in `ewm(span = 2, min_periods = 3, adjust=True)` for example, I want to take the values ​​from the dataframe corresponding to the "name" column : `ewm(span = df["span"], min_periods = df["min_periods"], adjust=True)`
I can't seem to make an example output

I would like to use dataframe values `​​"span"` and `"min_periods"` as parameter in ewm function but I can't.
I tested these 3 versions and none works, anyone have an idea please?

```
df = df.groupby(["name"]).ewm(span = df["span"], min_periods = df["min_periods"], adjust=True).mean() # test 1
df = df.groupby(["name"]).ewm(span = df["span"].astype(int), min_periods = df["min_periods"].astype(int), adjust=True).mean() # test 2
df = df.groupby(["name", "span", "min_periods"]).ewm(span = df["span"], min_periods = df["min_periods"], adjust=True).mean() # test 3
```

thank you all

Comment: in plain English explain what are you trying to do with an example , also provide expected result

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a series is passed as a parameter to ewm() whereas it expects the parameter to be a scalar.
It seems that for a given name, the span and the min period are always the same. If so, to get the span and period for the name 'a' for example, you could write:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("name")
name = 'a'
myspan = grouped_df.get_group(name)['span'].mean() 
myperiod = grouped_df.get_group(name)['min_periods'].mean()
```

And if you want to get the exponential average for score_1:

```
df['ewm_score_1'] = df['score_1'].ewm(span = myspan, min_periods = myperiod, adjust=True).mean()
```